# How to couple JMeter with Jenkins?

Tags: jmeter, jenkins, jmeter-plugins, continuous-integration

I'm trying to setup Jenkins on my laptop to run JMeter scripts. I have setup the job on the localhost also added the plugin required in JMeter. My window batch command looks like:

C:\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\delhivery\Desktop\Create.jmx -l C:\Users\delhivery\Desktop\Created.jtl

The build is getting executed successfully but the script doesn't actually get executed. The console output displays this message:

```
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation.
errorlevel=2
Press any key to continue . . . 
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: What's in `jmeter.bat`?  Sounds like it's trying to run the batch script, and that the system it's running on doesn't know about `findstr`

Comment: Am I the only one wondering what the motivation is for running loadtests(JMeter) in a continuous integration/deployment framework (Jenkins)? It seems to me like JMeter tests are a clear example of the kind of test you *don't* want to have in your build process but should run manually or through a scheduler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter startup script checks for Java version using [Findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732459%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) program. On "normal" Windows installation the `Findstr` program should exist in `C:\Windows\System32` directory therefore it should be on your system [PATH](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

So if you fix this issue by either fixing your system PATH or copying the `findstr.exe` file to the "bin" folder of your Java or JMeter installation you should be in position to run your JMeter test.

Detailed steps on Jenkins build configuration you can find in the [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article.

Comment: Thanks! Copying the findstr.exe file into the JMeter bin folder worked. A couple of questions though:
- The post build action of publishing performance test report doesn't have JMeter option. Do I need to add any other plugin as well!
- The workspace contains only log file post every build not the jtl file?

Answer (score 1):

By seeing the given error, issue might be in your java environment variable configuration.
When running jmeter.bat in command prompt manually without Jenkins, is it working?

In Jenkins, We can configure any batch or shell script and can schedule the job.

We can execute the Jmeter script in two ways:

With the setup of job by configuring the project by running batch command. In this case no need of the plugin.

Create a freestyle project.
Configure the batch command.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/How+to+run+JMeter+with+Jenkins

Screenshots given.
[image: batchfile sample]

[image: Jenkins project configuration]